# Why is my model.addRow function not working?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablemodel

The goal of the code is to add an object to my jTable. I have two classes called Task and TaskUI.

My initial expectation was to see a MessageDialog that says "Valid Task Details" and my object being added to the jTable. However, the only successful event was the program displaying the MessageDialog.

I have not received any syntax, logical or runtime error messages.

I have initially attempted to follow a step-by-step approach at creating a to-do list through this video: [ToDo List in JAVA Netbeans](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X5VkkBuR0SA&list=PLgcwxX88fVllGMSkJFfRhIAMmxjZblpS8&index=81&t=203s) but I feel that there is not enough separation between the UI and working code. What I mean by this is that a backend cannot be 'plugged into' a different UI that uses all the methods appropriately.

**Please note that I have recently edited the code, however, I need help to add the addTask() method**

**Task**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

public class Task {
private String name;
private String priority;
private String type;
private String time;
private boolean complete;

public Task(String name, String priority, String type, String time, boolean complete) {
    this.name = name;
    this.priority = priority;
    this.type = type;
    this.time = time;
    this.complete = complete;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getPriority() {
    return priority;
}

public void setPriority(String priority) {
    this.priority = priority;
}

public String getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}

public String getTime() {
    return time;
}

public void setTime(String time) {
    this.time = time;
}

public boolean isComplete() {
    return complete;
}

public void setComplete(boolean complete) {
    this.complete = complete;
}

public class TaskTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
    
    private String[] columnNames = {"Task","Priority","Type","Estimated Time","Status"};

    private List<Task> tasks;
    
    public TaskTableModel() {
        tasks = new ArrayList<Task>();
    }
    
    public TaskTableModel(List<Task> tasks) {
        this.tasks = tasks;
    }
    
    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return columnNames.length;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int column) {
        return columnNames[column];
    }
    
    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return tasks.size();
    }        

    @Override
    public Class getColumnClass(int column) {
        switch (column) {
            case 4: return boolean.class;
            default: return String.class;
        }
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
        switch (column) {
            case 4: return true;
            default: return false;
        }
    }
    
    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int row, int column) {
        Task task = getTask(row);
        switch (column) {
            case 0: return task.getName();
            case 1: return task.getPriority();
            case 2: return task.getType();
            case 3: return task.getTime();
            case 4: return task.isComplete();
            default: return null;
        }
    }
    
    @Override
    public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int column) {
        Task task = getTask(row);
        switch (column) {
            case 0: task.setName((String)value);  
            break;
            case 1: task.setPriority((String)value);
            break;
            case 2: task.setType((String)value);
            break;
            case 3: task.setTime((String)value);
            break;
            case 4: task.setComplete((boolean)value);
            break;
        }
        fireTableCellUpdated(row, column);
    }
    
    public Task getTask(int row) {
        return tasks.get(row);
    }
    
    public void addTask(Task task) {
        insertTask(getRowCount(), task);
    }
    
    public void insertTask(int row, Task task) {
        tasks.add(row, task);
        fireTableRowsInserted(row, row);
    }
    
    public void removeTask(int row) {
        tasks.remove(row);
        fireTableRowsDeleted(row, row);
    }
}//end TaskTableModel

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Task{" + "name=" + name + ", priority=" + priority + ", type=" + type + ", time=" + time + ", complete=" + complete + '}';
}
}//end Task
```

**TaskUI**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class TaskUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {
   boolean validTask;
   Task obj;
   DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();

   /**
   * Creates new form TaskUI
   */
   public TaskUI() {
       initComponents();
   }

  private void btnMakeObjectActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
    String name = txfTask.getText();
    String priority = (String) cmbPriority.getSelectedItem();
    String type = (String) cmbType.getSelectedItem();
    String time = txfTime.getText();
    boolean complete = false;
    if(txfTask.getText().length() > 0 && cmbPriority.getSelectedItem() != "--" && cmbType.getSelectedItem() != "--" && txfTime.getText().length() > 0) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Valid Task Details");
        validTask = true;
        obj = new Task (name,priority,type,time,complete);
        /**The following error message appears when adding the addTask(...) method:
         * cannot find symbol
         * symbol:   method addTask(Object[])
         * location: variable model of type DefaultTableModel
         */
        model.addTask(new Object[]{tblTaskInfo.getRowCount()+1, obj});
    }
    else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Task Details");
    }   
}
```

}

Here is a picture of my UI
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVbXl.png)

Comment: *The goal of the code is to add an object to my jTable* - what table? All your code does is create a model. You never add the model to a table or the table to the frame. Also, you can't add a custom object (Task) directly to the DefaultTableModel. The model will not know how to display the data. You need to create a custom table model. See: [Row Table Model](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/21/row-table-model/) for an example of how to create a custom model for your Task object.

Comment: @camickr I have followed the guidelines on the link you have sent but I am not sure how to implement it into my TaskUI class where I will be using a jTable swing control.

Comment: Only [use `Object.equals` to compare strings](https://www.javatpoint.com/how-to-compare-two-objects-in-java) (or any other non-trivial object, except `BigDecimal` objects). Do not use `!=` or `==` or any other such expressions. Applied to a part of your code fragment as an example: do not write `cmbPriority.getSelectedItem() != "--"`, instead write `!cmbPriority.getSelectedItem().equals("--")`. Do this for any comparison to strings in your code.

Comment: You use it the same way you use any TableModel except you 1) create your "Task" object and then 2) invoke the addTask(...) method to add the Task object to the model. Post a proper [mre] if you need more help.

Comment: @camickr I have created my Task object in my TaskUI class, however, I cannot invoke the addTask(...) method to my TaskUI. Can you please explain why and how to do it? Thanks in advance. You have really helped me.

Comment: Additionally, thank you @TT. for your suggestion. I shall implement it into my code.

Comment: Good. One small addendum to my comment: to compare BigDecimal objects, use the [`compareTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#compareTo(java.math.BigDecimal)) method.

Comment: Your old code used `model.addRow(...)`. That part of your code is simply replaced by `model.addTask(...)`. This means that when you create your JTable yiou add the `TaskTableModel` to the table so that you can add data to the model.

Comment: @camickr and to whoever can assist me. I have replaced the model.addRow(...) method with the model.addTask(...), however, it is giving me an error (I commented the error message in the TaskUI class). Please can you assist me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Should be `model.addTask(obj);`. You also are still comparing strings using == and != which is an error (although not a compile error).

Comment: Oh and the type of your model needs to be `TaskTableModel`, so make it `TaskTableModel model = new TaskTableModel();`

Comment: @TT. When I type `TaskTableModel model = new TaskTableModel();`  the IDE suggests that I should create a TaskTableModel class in the package or in the TaskUI class. Does this mean that I need to take out the `public class TaskTableModel extends AbstractTableModel` form the Task class?

Comment: You need to create a **separate class file** for your TaskTableModel class. Then, import TaskTableModel in your TaskUI class to be able to use it there.

Comment: @TT. Thank you for the advice. I appreciate it.